# UK Visa Courier Address

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I am applying for a tourist visa for UK from New York. I have completed my application and now need to purchase the round-trip courier service. The instructions on the website say to use VFS. But the VFS site is broken and I am not able to use it.

There are a few questions on this forum which say that I should be able to purchase it directly from UPS/USPS etc. If I want to do this, what address should I provide? Is this address listed on the UK immigration website anywhere?

Thanks.

Comment: VFS uses different addresses for different types of applications, so you must obtain the specific address from VFS. Wait a bit, and/or try a different computer, and/or try a different browser, and/or contact VFS technical assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The address for submitting your visa application is listed in the UK Government's web site for how to [apply for a UK visa from the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).

This address changes over time. At the time of writing, it was:

VFS Services USA Inc.
UKVI Scanning Hub
80 Broad Street
Floor 6
New York, 10004

And yes, you currently can and should purchase your own shipping labels. You can go to a UPS Store or buy them online from UPS if you have a label printer. Keep in mind that you can only use air services (2nd day or next day air) for the return service back to your address.